# Want to create a function for each pin of the Arduino board using templates

Tags: c++, c++11, arduino, c++14, arduino-c++

So I'm working with pots and I want to smooth out the measurements. So I created a function that takes ten measurements and returns the average and I want to be able to call it the same way I would call `analogRead()`. So I created a template for this purpose, here's the code:

```
template<const uint8_t& PIN>
unsigned smoothReading(const uint8_t& PIN)
{
  static unsigned sample[10];
  static unsigned currentUnit = 0;


  if(currentUnit < 9) currentUnit++;
  else currentUnit = 0;

  sample[currentUnit] = analogRead(PIN);

  double average = 0;
  for (const auto& unit : sample)
    average += unit;
  
  average = average / 10;

  return round(average);
}
```

As you can see, I have some static variables which can't be shared among function calls for each pin. To be more precise, each pin has its own sample array of measurements, etc. So I have to either write this as a template; or have one single function and global variables for each pin I want to measure; or declare multiple versions of the function for each pin I want to measure. So I prefer just using a template.

The problem is, I keep getting `shadows template parm` errors. So,does the compiler think I'm trying to declare two different parameters with the same name? How can I make the template parameter resolve to the function parameter? Is there any other reason for this error?

Comment: Two questions: 1) why have a reference-to-const template parameter in `template<const uint8_t& PIN>` if `template<uint8_t PIN>` is easier to use? and 2) why additionally accept a function parameter `const uint8_t& PIN` if it's thoroughly redundant? Your function signature should be simply `template<uint8_t PIN> unsigned smoothReading()`, to be used as `unigned x = smoothReading<15>();` Unless, do you ever need to choose pins at runtime?

Comment: Question 1: Because I'm working at very high frequencies and I need to get a reading with as little overhead as posible. It does work, I just had to declare the pins as  `extern const uint8_t pinX = X;` (where x is an lvalue literal). Question 2:  That's actually a great idea, I just tried it and it compiled. I wanted to be able to use the function basically de same way as `analogRead()`, meaning, I wanted to be able to just pass in a pin and have the compiler create a new function for me. But calling it as 'smoothReading<pinX>()' is basically the same thing, so I will just stick to that.

Comment: I believe you misunderstand how non-type template arguments work. `template<uint8_t PIN>` means that the `PIN` parameter is treated as a compile-time constant and can be inlined wherever possible. `template<const uint8_t& PIN>` on the other hand means that `PIN` is not a constant, but rather an indirect reference to a global variable which needs to take up extra memory and memory reads, preventing optimizations.

Comment: You're totally right. I'll stick with `template<uint8_t PIN>`. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

So this is the solution I came up with:

```
template<uint8_t PIN>
unsigned smoothReading()
{
  static unsigned sample[20];
  static unsigned currentUnit = 0;

  if(currentUnit < 19) currentUnit++;
  else currentUnit = 0;

  sample[currentUnit] = analogRead(PIN);

  double average = 0;
  for (const auto& unit : sample)
    average += unit;
  
  average = average / 20;

  return (unsigned)average;
}
```

You call it as `smoothReading<[desired pin]>()`. It's very similar to analogRead(), but you'll get the average of 10 readings.

Comment: Any reason for not using the [RunningAverage](https://github.com/RobTillaart/RunningAverage) library instead of doing it manually? You could pass a second parameter to your template for the number of samples to be averaged.

Comment: Cause it's just ten lines of code. I don't need a whole library to implement this feature :)